# pandas dataframe subsetting showing NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have two pandas dataframes df1 and df2 where age, Start_Time, End_Time are datetime64[ns] dtypes. I want to extract data points in df1 which are falling within any of Start_Time           End_Time in df2

```
df1   
      age                   LAeq    LSeq Doss   LSeq Gliss  LZeq    
0   2019-05-14 15:40       62.02    NaN               NaN   0.0     
1   31-01-2019 15:39       60.45    NaN               NaN   0.0     

df2
       index            Start_Time            End_Time           Equipment_Group        
       3200         2019-05-14 08:00:00    2019-05-14 16:00:00  Atmospheric_Vacts   
       4856         2019-07-22 08:00:00    2019-07-22 16:00:00  Atmospheric_Vacts


for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    start = row['Start_Time']
    end = row['End_Time']
    df1.loc[df1['age'].between(start, end) , 'ACTIVE'] = True
df1.head()
```

I am getting 'NaN'  in ACTIVE column instead of True. It will be helpful, if I can get some direction on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fill non-active values with `False`:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    start = row['Start_Time']
    end = row['End_Time']
    df1.loc[df1['age'].between(start, end) , 'ACTIVE'] = True
    df1['ACTIVE'] = df1['ACTIVE'].fillna(False)
df1.head()
```